# How to short Timing Array Data with From and To keys

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs

This is JSON of random timing data in 24 hours format

```
var timeArray = [
    {from: "17:00:00", to: "18:00:00"},
    {from: "09:45:00", to: "14:30:00"},
    {from: "20:00:00", to: "23:45:00"}];
```

expected output is sorted like

```
var timeArray = [
    {from: "09:45:00", to: "14:30:00"},
    {from: "17:00:00", to: "18:00:00"},
    {from: "20:00:00", to: "23:45:00"}];
```

is there any logic or function to achieve this in javascript or angularjs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var timeArray = [
  { from: "09:45:00", to: "14:30:00" },
  { from: "17:00:00", to: "18:00:00" },
  { from: "20:00:00", to: "23:45:00" }
];
console.log(timeArray.sort((a, b) => b.from > a.from ? -1 : 1))
```

Answer (score 2):

By using time strings with a padded format (with zeroes) with descending groups, like hour, minute, second, you could take a standard sort for strings.

```js
var timeArray = [{ from: "17:00:00", to: "18:00:00" }, { from: "09:45:00", to: "14:30:00" }, { from: "20:00:00", to: "23:45:00" }];

timeArray.sort((a, b) => a.from.localeCompare(b.from));

console.log(timeArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this way

```
var timeArray = [
    {from: "17:00:00", to: "18:00:00"},
    {from: "09:45:00", to: "14:30:00"},
    {from: "20:00:00", to: "23:45:00"}];


console.log(
    _.sortBy( timeArray, function( item ) { return item.from; } )
);
```

For this you have to add underscore js library from [here](https://underscorejs.org/)

Answer (score 1):

I see you tagged this with `momentjs`. So using moment we can do something like this.

```
timeArray.sort((a, b) => {
  var aMoment = moment(a.from, "h:mm:ss");
  var bMoment = moment(b.from, "h:mm:ss");
  return aMoment.diff(bMoment);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use moments diff method for this

```js
const timeArray = [
  { from: "17:00:00", to: "18:00:00" },
  { from: "09:45:00", to: "14:30:00" },
  { from: "20:00:00", to: "23:45:00" }
];

timeArray.sort((a, b) => {

  const fromA = moment(a.from, 'HH:mm:ss');
  const fromB = moment(b.from, 'HH:mm:ss');
  
  return fromA.diff(fromB);
});

console.log(timeArray);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.2.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```